# Ruby: Gather twitter data based on Location

Tags: ruby, twitter, geolocation

I'm trying to gather twitter based on location. I'd like some hints into how to gather:

1. Tweets coming from the Greek community
2. Tweets coming from all over (public streamline)
3. Tweets coming from Greece (location-based)
4. Tweets having a specific keyword

I'm using **Ruby** and will probably go with [tweetstream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream). The alternative is to work directly with the [twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/). Note that **tweetstream** is based upon **twitter-gem**, made by the same developers, etc. It's just a higher abstraction layer with some handy add-ons like event-machine-driven start/stop daemon.

**For point 1**, it's hard to say if someone is Greek. The only approach I can think of, is gather all tweets from [public streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public) and filter tweets containing Greek words.

**For point 2**, okay I'll go using `Tweetstream::Client.new.sample`

**For point3**, I have no idea. The GPS coordinates of Greece are Latitude: **N 39° 0' 0''**    and longitude **E 22° 0' 0**, but that's just a *point on the map* not the Greek territory. I know Tweetstream supports a couple o methods to define location-based tweets but I don't have a clue on how to approach this... Any ideas, hints or thoughts are welcome.

**For point4** I'm using TweatStream::Client.new.track('keyword') which keeps the connection up and running. Reading twitter's Streaming API, I have the impression that

Best Regards,

PA

Comment: Such as http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/D/D12/D12-1137.pdf ?

Comment: That's a paper, I'm looking for a more straight-forward answer. However thanks, it have some insights as how to approach this. Reading the twitter's JSON Api was also useful, they allow using a point (long/lat) and a radius, which makes sense...

Comment: Only a small part is geotagged, the rest is non-trivial.